# Is it allowed to post "Did anyone find a solution?" as an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, rules

Is it allowed to post a "did any body get any solution to the above question" as an answer ??

Example :   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987019/qt-top-level-widget-with-keyboard-and-mouse-event-transparency/2011467#2011467)

Comment: Did any body get any solution to the above question? Why is it marked as unanswered?

Answer (score 10):

No.  That's not a real answer.  It should be a comment.  If you find these in the future, tell the "answerer" that their answer should be a comment in a comment on their answer (as I've done on this answer) then flag it for moderator attention so they can clean it up if the "answerer" doesn't (which I've also done in this case).

Comment: thanks , i was planning to leave a similar comment and flag it, but didn't know which flag to use :)

Comment: In general, if it's not obvious that it's spam or offensive, but it definitely needs some love, then flag it for the mods and explain what you think is wrong.  The worst that can happen is that the mods think you're wrong and they ignore your request...

Comment: womble, please change your name. It's hard to refer to someone as Unknown Yahoo. Also, +1 on the answer.

Comment: Bah, why can't I have a cool meta name like all the other children?  <stamps foot> <pouts>

Answer (score 0):

As Unknown Yahoo said, the answer is no - however, he only has 1 reputation so he isn't able to leave comments.

... Not really sure what he can do as if he posted the question again, it would be a duplicate and obviously he just wants to bring people's attention to the question.

Comment: he did post the question again :)

Comment: I haven't done any Qt in years, but it really looks like a dupe, and should be voted-to-close as such.  It's not as though there aren't enough answers on the other question to try out and then cite as to why they don't work in a separate question.  My gut says that the "correct" answer there is "it's not possible", based on my very limited understanding of X.